# Misunderstanding about the current flowing path

Tags: current, charge

[image]

The author shows the working process of this schematic.

1. The proposed system waits until the PZT device stores the energy vibrations produced during the positive half of vibration period \$T_{VIB}\$ before engaging switches \$S_I\$ and \$S_N\$ to discharge \$C_{PZT}\$ into off-chip harvesting inductor \$L_H\$.
2. The inductor current \$i_L\$ rises to reach the peak, then the switches \$M_{P1}\$ and \$S_I\$ de-energize \$L_H\$ into the battery via \$i_{BAT}^+\$.
3. The system again waits for the transducer to energize \$C_{PZT}\$ (in the negative direction) through the negative half of \$T_{VIB}\$ before prompting \$S_I\$ and \$S_N\$ to discharge \$C_{PZT}\$ into \$L_H\$, after which \$M_{P2}\$ and \$S_N\$ deenergize \$L_H\$ into the battery.

I sorted out what the author said:

1. The PZT will produce energy first, then \$S_I\$ and \$S_N\$  will be "on" to let the current flow from \$C_{PZT}\$ to \$L_H\$.
2. \$M_{P1}\$ and \$S_I\$ disconnect, and let the \$i_{BAT}^+\$ flow from the \$L_H\$ into the battery.
3. When the PZT produces the negative part of the voltage, \$S_I\$ and \$S_N\$ are "on", and the negative current flows from the \$C_{PZT}\$ to \$L_H\$ (this current direction is the opposite of 1. current direction in the \$L_H\$  ), then \$M_{P2}\$ and \$S_N\$ disconnect to let the current flow from the \$L_H\$ into the battery.

Hold on a second, I have a question about the 2. and 3.: if the \$M_{P1}\$ and \$S_I\$ disconnect, why can the \$i_{BAT}^+\$ flow from the \$L_H\$ to the battery? Why can \$M_{P2}\$ and \$S_N\$ disconnect to let the current flow from the \$L_H\$ to the battery? It seems that I misunderstand something from the author saying, but I don't know which part do I misunderstand, can anyone correct my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

After  +ve swing of Cpzt:  Dump charge into L current then release low side of +ve current as V+ into Vbat with CP1.

After -ve swing of Cpzt: Dump -ve charge into L current then release hi side of -ve current also as V+ into Vbat with CP2.

Comment: Sir,i read the some part of the paper,the schematic is also from this paper,can you tell me your thinking or correct my mistake if i am wrong?

Comment: I corrected your thinking in my answer. It’s a full wave rectifier

Comment: but sir,the topic of this paper is "A 2um BiCMOS Rectiﬁer-Free AC–DC Piezoelectric Energy Harvester-Charger IC "

Comment: I did not read topic, but I can read schematics. This is a boost flyback rectified current from a sinusoid piezoelectric. Charge up voltage is shunted to inductor L current then switched to charged  Vbat, based on current polarity.

Comment: CP1 and CP2 are "active rectifiers", not *rectifiers,* not pn junctions.  Their Vf can be far below the 0.7V of a junction rectifier.   The circuit is not rectifier-free.  Instead it avoids use of pn junction rectifiers.

Comment: Yes of course the comparator senses when input voltage exceeds Vbat and enables low RdsON Nfet, but still performing as (a more ideal) current rectifier